# Convert this web script to an actual SQL View

Tags: sql-server, view

Ok.. I have atleast 5 tables that have information in what I call a queue.  From a work order ID I want to see if there is an unclosed queue entry and if so come back with the queue name.  Here is the script I query from a web page to get the information.

```
DECLARE @WO_ID nvarchar(30), @WO_QUEUES nvarchar(max), @QUEUE_COUNT smallint; 

SET @QUEUE_COUNT = 0 
SET @WO_ID = '17-0285' 
SET @WO_QUEUES = '' 



IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, AQL_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_AQL WHERE (AQL_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL) AND (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 SET @WO_QUEUES = 'QUALITY AQL ' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, BLENDING_PAGE_SENT_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_BLENDING WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (BLENDING_PAGE_SENT_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'BLENDING' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, BS_REVIEW_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_BS_REVIEW WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (BS_REVIEW_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'BS REVIEW' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, HOLD_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_HOLDS WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (HOLD_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'HOLD ' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, LAB_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_LAB WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (LAB_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'LAB ' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, MATMGT_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_MATMGT WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (MATMGT_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'MATERIAL MANAGEMENT' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, NCMR_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_NCMR WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (NCMR_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'QUALITY NCMR ' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, PICK_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_PICK WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (PICK_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'MATERIAL PICK ' END 

IF EXISTS (SELECT WO_NUMBER, SHIP_COMPLETED_DATETIME FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_SHIP WHERE (WO_NUMBER = @WO_ID) AND (SHIP_COMPLETED_DATETIME IS NULL)) 
BEGIN SET @QUEUE_COUNT = @QUEUE_COUNT + 1 

IF LEN(@WO_QUEUES) > 0 
BEGIN SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + ', ' END SET @WO_QUEUES = @WO_QUEUES + 'SHIPPING ' END SELECT @WO_QUEUES AS QUEUES, @QUEUE_COUNT AS QUEUE_COUNT
```

The result I get is this

```
QUEUES                          QUEUE_COUNT
MATERIAL MANAGEMENT, SHIPPING   2
```

I am going brain dead trying to figure the most efficient way to get this to be in a view so I can put in the WO ID as my filter and get the queues.

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, there are a number of ways you could tackle this. My first thought is to put it in a CTE with a `CROSS APPLY` on the columns (e.g. `WITH CTE AS (SELECT C.Q FROM DLI_WORK_ORDER_TRACKING_PICK AS T CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('QUALITY AQL', AQL_COMPLETED_DATETIME), ('BLENDING', BLENDING_PAGE_SENT_DATETIME),('BS REVIEW', BS_REVIEW_COMPLETED_DATETIME)...) AS C(Q, Val) WHERE T.WO_ID = @WO_ID AND C.Val IS NOT NULL)`) then use a stuff statement + count(*) from the CTE (e.g. `SELECT QUEUES = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Q FROM CTE FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, ''), QUEUE_COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM CTE;`).

Comment: I kinda follow what you are saying but unable to put your vision into an actual query.  I can do basic SQL and not very good at advanced stuff.

Comment: You shouldn't really need much in addition to what I wrote. I believe combining those two should get your desired output. All you need to do after that is `CREATE VIEW myViewName AS WITH CTE AS (<insert CTE>) SELECT QUEUES = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Q FROM CTE FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, ''), QUEUE_COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM CTE;`